# Why do functions change arrays passed in as arguments?

Tags: python, list

I have this code:

```
def change_element(list, index, new_element):
    list[index] = new_element
    return list

example_list = [1, 2, 3]
new_list = change_element(example_list, -1, 4)
print example_list
print new_list
```

I don't want the variable "example_list" to be changed. I believe that the function "change_element" argument "list" is a pointer to "example_list", so when "list" is changed, "example_list" is changed. Even with this (below), "example_list" is still changed.

```
def change_element(list, index, new_element):
    return_list = list
    return_list[index] = new_element
    return return_list

example_list = [1, 2, 3]
new_list = change_element(example_list, -1, 4)
print example_list
print new_list
```

How do I prevent this from happening?
I know this is possible with loops, but the lists I want to iterate are large. (maybe greater than 10,000 elements)

Comment: I think the question here is a lot simpler than the one it's marked as a "duplicate" of.  The basic answer is that lists are mutable, and the function is just passing a reference to the list.  In your second example, copying also means that you're just creating a second reference to the same list.  To do what you want, you should make a copy at some point - e.g. by passing in `example_list[:]`, or using `return_list = list[:]` in your second example.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering, does `[:]` use a loop?

Comment: Yes, it makes a full copy of the list, which will ultimately use a loop of some sort under the hood.